# Import redux-persist into Typescript project with Atom, Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, atom-editor, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to build a project with Typescript and [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) (npm). I want to bundle the application with Webpack.

The import statement from the redux-persist site is `import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from '../../node_modules/redux-persist'`

I'm using the Atom editor. The editor's import autocomplete doesn't recognise the module that I'm trying to import. Even if I type the full path to the module, I still get an error `can't find module`.

The export from redux-persist appears to be an ES6/Babel style export. Is there a way to make that work with Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same issue and my solution matches one mentioned in project [issue tracker](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/135):

```
const persistStore = require('redux-persist').persistStore;
const autoRehydrate = require('redux-persist').autoRehydrate;
```

Doesn't complain in Webstorm.